# How can I force a child class to assign a unique value to an inherited field?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, field

Say I have a parent class:

```
Public MustInherit Class ParentClass
    Protected str As String
    Public MustOverride Sub Method()
End Class
```

And then I have a child class:

```
Public Class ChildClass
    Inherits ParentClass
    Public Overrides Sub Method()
    End Sub
End Class
```

At the moment I have no way to ensure that `str` is assigned a unique value (a value which will be different for each class that inherits `ParentClass`).

Is there any way to force any child classes (even ones that I don't create) to assign `str` a value, similar to how `MustOverride` forces the child class to implement `Method()`? I thought there might a `MustAssign` keyword but there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I think I've reasoned out a way to do this myself.

I will create a protected constructor in ParentClass that takes a String and assign it to the field.

In `ParentClass`:

```
Protected Sub New(ByVal s As String)
    Me.str = s
End Sub
```

Now, every class must implement a constructor that calls the single `ParentClass` constructor which takes a String.

In `ChildClass`

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("String")
End Sub
```

This seems to solve my problem.

Is there a better method to solving this problem, or have I hit the nail on the head?

Comment: If the string should be unique for each child *instance* then the parent ought not have anything to do with it.  Depending on what it is, I am not sure that the calling code ought to specify the unique value.

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry, I needed to clarify. The field should be unique to each *child class*, not each *child instance*. So all instances of `ChildClass1` should set `str` to the same value, all instances of `ChildClass2` should set `str` to a different value from `ChildClass1`, etc. All instances of the same child class should have a unique, identical `str` value. Typing this now makes me think this should be a `Shared` value, but `Shared` only in the scope of each child class. Can this be done? Each child class has an inherited shared field with a different value for each child class?

Comment: You will need to write a new class for each Type, perhaps use an interface to provide the identifier contract.  I suspect this is an XY problem though, because code such as `MyBase.New("String")` is setting the *instance* identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Use name Class, ensure the unique value

```
Public MustInherit Class ParentClass
    Protected str As String = Me.GetType.Name
    Public MustOverride Sub Method()
End Class
```

Beware, in your solution, there is nothing to prevent two daughters classes with the same initialization.

Comment: Yes I'm fine with two children initializing the field to the same value. Unfortunately, I need the `str` field to contain a specific sequence of non-alphanumeric characters that can't be in the name of a class, so I can't really take advantage of the solution this way.

Comment: Now that I've studied this moreI think I can take advantage of having the value not be `Shared` for each class, ie have the field by instance based, so I am going to go about implementing my constructor solution below. Thanks for your input!

Comment: You could use [custom attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx), ideal for class metadata .

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible patterns is to use a getter function instead of a field. Define it in each of the child classes. It may or may not be what you want.

```
Public MustOverride Function Str() As String
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is more about forcing any child class that *other people* make to assign this field a value. If I can ensure that this getter is called in a constructor, this would solve my problem, but I can't. I believe I figured out a proper solution to this problem, take a look at my answer above and leave any comments you have!